# Issue "translating" raw SQL to SQLAlchemy ORM query

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following raw SQL statement that I am having trouble "translating" into a SQLAlchemy query:

(the hardcoded value 38 is just for testing)

```
SELECT * FROM public.data_appquestion AS question

    /* ANSWER JOIN */
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM public.data_appanswer) AS answer
        ON (
            answer.separation_app_question_id = question.id 
            AND answer.is_active = true
            AND answer.separation_app_session_id = 38
        )
    /* OPTION XREFS JOIN */ 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM public.data_appansweroptionxref) AS options_xref
        ON (
            options_xref.separation_app_answer_id = answer.id 
        )
    /* OPTIONs JOIN */  
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM public.data_appoption) AS answered_option
        ON (
            options_xref.separation_app_option_id = answered_option.id 
        )
    /* UPLOAD JOIN */
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM public.data_appfileupload) AS uploads
        ON (
            uploads.separation_app_answer_id = answer.id 
        )

    WHERE question.is_active = true
        AND answer.is_active = true
        OR answer.is_active = NULL
        AND options_xref.is_active = true
        OR options_xref.is_active = NULL
        AND uploads.to_delete = false
        OR uploads.to_delete = NULL

    ORDER BY question.id;
```

I have tried something like this, but the "filter" statement already does not seem to work as I need it to:

```
db_questions = db.query(models.AppQuestion).\
        filter(models.AppQuestion.is_active == True).\
        outerjoin(models.AppAnswer, and_(
            models.AppAnswer.app_question_id == models.AppQuestion.id,
            models.AppAnswer.app_session_id == 38
            )
        ).\
        outerjoin(models.AppAnswer.app_options).\
        outerjoin(models.AppAnswerOptionXref.app_option).\
        outerjoin(models.AppFileUpload.app_question).\
        order_by(asc(models.AppQuestion.order_number)).all()
```

The models all have the relevant "relationship" entries, so there is no issue for the query to find the relevant models via their foreign keys. The issue is that they are not filtered as they are in the raw SQL.

My result includes a joined "AppAnswer", but it does not filter it according to ```app_session_id == 38````

I'm not very familiar with joining SQL queries and usually working with the Django ORM, which never had me run into an issue like this.

Let me know if I need to add more info and thanks a lot for any replies!

Comment: As coded you get ALL questions, but then only join on the answers from app_session_id 38. Is that intended? (That if the answer is from a different session, you still want the question anyway?)

Comment: @MatBailie The intention is: (1) Get all questions that are "active", (2) Join all answers to each Question that were given in session 38, (3) Join all selected Options via the "AnswerOptionXref" n:n table, (4) Join all Uploads for this question. --> So yes, ALL questions (active), but only answers from session 38. --> The issue is that the result has the first answer joined to it, independent of the session ID (in my case it's 26, so the "filter" seems to be ignored.)